# Is it better to use find() and end() function to chain the code?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the HTML code as below:

```
<div class="body">
    <div class="head">xxx</div>
    <div class="menu">xxx</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="main">xxx</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script A**

```
$('.body')
  .find('.head').show().end()
  .find('.menu').show().end()
  .find('.content .main').show().end()
```

**Script B**

```
$('.body .head').show()
$('.body .menu').show()
$('.body .content .main').show()
```

I have written the script **A** and **B** to show all elements, but which is better or what is the advantage of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's subjective, I find `end` less readable some may disagree.
**There isn't right or wrong answers.**

I prefer the caching style as it's more readable and even a bit faster.

**Script C**

```
var $body = $('.body');
$body.find('.head').show();
$body.find('.menu').show();
$body.find('.content .main').show();
```

Note that:

```
$body.find('.head').show();
$body.find('.menu').show();
```

Could be shortened-combined to:

```
$body.find('.head, .menu').show();
```

> The end() method is useful primarily when exploiting jQuery's chaining properties. When not using chaining, we can usually just call up a previous object by variable name, so we don't need to manipulate the stack. With end(), though, we can string all the method calls together.

[From the docs](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

Comment: I know that we can add more selector in `$(xxx)`, but I would like to know the different or advantage or use `find()` and `end()`, thanks.

Comment: @CharlesYeung, It's subjective, I find `end` less readable some may disagree. there isn't right or wrong answers.

Comment: @CharlesYeung, the point of this approach isn't combining selectors, it's saving the initial selector in a variable and using that variable as needed. I'm with gdoron on this, I think the code is a lot easier to understand this way.

Comment: @gdoron, a suggestion: maybe it would help for purposes of illustration if you split that `'.head, .menu'` selector back into two separate lines? That would make it more parallel in structure to the the Script A and Script B approaches.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no other elements inside the `.body`, I would just call `.show()` or `.hide()` on `.body`.

```
$('.body').show();
```

Or if there are just part of the children of `.body` div, you could write just one line:

```
$('.body').find('.head,.menu,.content .main').show();

// or provide the second parameter as the context
$('.head,.menu,.content .main', '.body').show();
```

Comment: +1. Nice, it seems we have a new [winner](http://jsperf.com/find-end-vs-newquery)

Answer (score 2):

Caching the value of `$('.body')` would be recommended here, either by storing it inside a variable or by using `.end()`.

This code also combines the `'.head'` and `'.menu'` selectors inside a single `.find()`:

```
$('.body')
    .find('.head,.menu')
        .show()
        .end()
    .find('.content .main')
        .show();
```

*Turns out this is ~5% slower than option A.*

Of course you can also go native and use `querySelectorAll()` directly:

```
[].forEach.call(document.body.querySelectorAll('.head, .menu, .content .main'), function(node) {
    node.style.display = 'block';
});
```

*This won't work on all browsers, but the performance increase is enormous.*

[**jsperf results**](http://jsperf.com/find-end-vs-newquery)

Comment: So you mean Script A is run faster then Script B? Thanks

Comment: I believe mine will be the fastest. can you add it? (my proxy block jsperf for some unknown reason)

Comment: @gdoron I just did, it's about as fast as mine :)

Comment: I guess the `,` selector isn't well implemented.

Comment: @Jack, well, Actually those tests aren't real tests as they don't run against a real document-HTML structure.

Comment: @Jack +1 for all answer and thanks for the info. But sorry, I still can't get the answer?

Comment: @CharlesYeung, If you want **the** answer: It does't matter, choose the style you find easier to write, read and maintain. the differences are very small in practice.

Comment: @CharlesYeung The answer is a combination of readability and performance compromise.

Comment: @CharlesYeung, do you really care if script A takes 0.00005 and script B takes 0.0001? be sure my friend, this won't be the weakest link in your app-chain.